# linking one arraylist to another

Tags: java, arraylist, split

I essentially need to know if I can change 1 arrayList into another arrayList and then make an association as to which item in arrayList 1, an item from arrayList 2 came from, without using a pattern finder. It is difficult to explain, so let illustrate it with a simple example:

Given file input:

```
Feline:
Cat Lion
Cheetah

Canine:
Dog
Wolves Fox
```

I split the file into each paragraph using:

```
String strLine;
String [] paragraph = strLine.split("");
```

From here I add each item to an arrayList by using an add method inside an advanced for loop.

This should leave us with the first arrayList:

```
[Feline: Cat Lion Cheetah, Canine: Dog Wolves Fox]
```

From there in need to split each item into separate words, using the regex \\s+. This should be easy with another advanced for loop.

This should leave us with the second arrayList:

```
[Feline:, Cat, Lion, Cheetah, Canine:, Dog, Wolves, Fox]
```

What I need to know is if there anyway for me to get the program to realise that the word Cheetah in the second arrayList originated from the first item in the first arrayList, without having to search the first arraylist for items in the second arrayList. The point has to be that the the one item in the one arrayList originates from the other arrayList.

I essentially need to do this because I have methods that depending what the the first word of each paragraph is, different things are done to each paragraph.

Let me know if my explanation is confusing and sorry about bad terminology, I'm having trouble explaining my problem.

If this is possible please let me know how I might go about solving my problem.

Regards

Comment: Why cant you use a map instead of arraylist and map some key to each paragraph words?

Comment: I haven't really used maps and hashMaps etc. so I'm not to familiar with how they work or what they do. How will a map be able to make the association I am talking about whilst retaining the layout/ abilities I need from an arrayList?

Comment: Or you can use a List in which each element will be a list of strings.The first element will be list of all words in first paragraph, second list will second paragraph words and so on

Comment: This something I've tried already, but if I ever need to then split it into each char, which is a possibility I might have, will I be able to do it by doing this?

Comment: Anytime you can get a string and split it into chars...If I got your question right:-)

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't what I meant. Will do some work with maps, and there is also another answer that was posted that I would like to try. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would propose to keep the initial array list position when you do the split based on the space character. Say for example you define an object as follows;

```
public class MyWord
{
private int pos;

private String word;
public MyWord(int pos,String word)
{
 this.pos = pos;

 this.word = word;
}
//getters and setters
}
```

Then when you split, you can do something like this;

```
List<MyWord>secondList = new ArrayList<MyWord>();
for(int i=0;i<firstList.size();i++)
{
 String[]words = firstList.get(i).split("\\s");
 for(String wordToAdd : words)
 {
  MyWord w = new MyWord(i,wordToAdd);
  secondList.add(w);
 }
}
```

So now your second list will have an object containing the word as well as the original index it contained in the first list.

Hops this helps.

Comment: Thanks, never occurred to me to try this, but it should work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your program is never going to 'realize' anything. Each of the Java collections has a specified semantics, and they do no more and no less that what they are documented to do.

`java.util.List` stores an ordered list of of objects. It does not detect duplicates. It does not maintain associations with anything else. You can ask a list 'do you contain X'? with the `contains` method. This takes time proportional to the number of things in the list.

When you store `String` objects in a list, there is no concept of where they come from. They are just in the list. If you need your second list to contain items that correlate to your first list, you need to code that. If *all* the second list needs to store is correlations to the first list, it could be a `List<Integer>`, and for each of those items you search for it in the first list to get the index. So, yes, as you process each of the items for the second list, you need to scan the first list to see if/where it is. It's not clear from your question what you want to have happen if something from the second group was not mentioned at all in the first group.

Comment: Sorry about the bad terminology, I do know that the program does not just understand things and make connections between items. Just didn't know how to explain my problem. Will see if a `List<Integer>` serves the function I require. Thanks